# how to send image over TCP socket from raspberry pi (client) to server (laptop)?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, opencv3.1

I am using raspberry pi 3 model B and Rpi camera B.(**OS is raspbian stretch**)
I want to send an image taken by raspberry pi to my laptop (**ubuntu 16.04**) via TCP.Raspberry pi and laptop are connected with wifi from router. But when I receive data, process it and save it.Then the result is not correct.
Here is my client.py

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.0.109'
TCP_PORT = 5000
# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280,720)
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
print('Connected to server')
# grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
image = rawCapture.array
encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)[1]


s.sendall(encoded)
print('Done')
s.close()
```

Here is my server.py

```
import socket
import struct
import cv2
import numpy as np
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

con = s.accept()[0]
print('Connected to client....')
count = 0

name = str(count)+'.jpg'
data = con.recv(4096)

encoded_array = np.fromstring(data,np.uint8)
decoded_image = cv2.imdecode(encoded_array,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imwrite(name,decoded_image)
s.close()
con.close()
```

[Here is my result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgsaM.jpg)

**Note:** Raspberry pi versions --> opencv 3.4.0 ,python 3.5.3

laptop versions --> opencv 3.1.0, python 3.5.2

Comment: are you reading **all** data? `data = con.recv(4096)` smells...

Comment: i don't know how to implement for receiving all data, could u help me with this?

Comment: Thanks alot dude :)